# Copy a whole bunch of files with their names being changed a little bit using shell script

Tags: shell, cp

I have a very large number of files with very similar names: row1col1.txt, row1col2.txt, row1col3.txt, row1col4.txt......

I'd like to make copies of them all and change the names to row2col1.txt, row2col2.txt,
row2col3,txt, row2col4.txt......

Using the cp command in shell script, how can I do it efficiently?

Comment: Do you mean you want to *always* increment the row number?  Or *only* increment the row number?  Will the column number ever need to be incremented?  Etc.  That's a good example to lead with, but if you could be just a bit more explicit on what exactly you want, it would help guide your responders.

Comment: I'd be inclined to make whatever uses these files accept the filenames as they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you going to generate the file names?  How are you going to specify the substitution?

One possibility is:

```
ls row1col*.txt |
sed 's/row1\(.*\)/cp & row2\1/' |
sh -x
```

This uses `ls` to generate the list of names, and `sed` to generate a `cp` command for each named file, and pipes that to `sh` so that the copy operations occur.  Don't run it to `sh` until you are confident that the rest is right.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the program `mcp` contained in the packet `mmv`, you can do that like this:

```
mcp row1\* row2\#1
```